# Unit test failed while run corda The example CorDapp(IOU)

Tags: corda

When i am running the unit test for corda example cordapp, i receive following error. Any idea will be helpful.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLEyNjQtQZHUgbZs7xwjivUPiaCz9pdgb49wWKaSjCTfq8)
at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:47)
at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupPublicKeysByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:21)
at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupPublicKeysByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:33)
at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:107)
at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:64)
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290)
at com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator.call(ExampleFlow.java:112)
at com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator.call(ExampleFlow.java:33)
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)
```

I can follow the guidelines to create an IOU, but the unit test failed.I downloaded the code from the official website and did not make any changes.

Comment: Which unit test is failing?

Comment: thank you for your help,5 test in IOU flow test failed.(only flowRejectsInvalidIOUs passed). They failed with same error.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the CorDapp you're downloading? I can't replicate on the Example CorDapp (github.com/corda/cordapp-example).

Comment: I solve this problem by re-download corda-3.2.jar. Thank you very much for trying  solving this problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by re-downloading the `corda-3.2.jar`.